# bipartite layout Gephi 0.9.1

Tags: layout, gephi, bipartite

my question is awkwardly simple:

how do i plot a bipartite graph in Gephi with a layout like the one you see in the attached image?
[image]

I really am not able to find an appropriate layout in Gephi's options

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gephi version 0.9.1 has an Event Graph Layout plugin that will do this: `Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins`. Under Data Laboratory, you'll need to add an integer-level variable to your Nodes data table ("Mode" for example), set all of your B nodes to 1, and all of your R nodes to 2. Select that variable in the Order setting of the layout options. You'll likely have to bump Scale of Order up to get decent separation between your modes.

Comment: I would vote this answer in the top 10 of  the most useful and hard to find elsewhere :) Thanks!

Comment: This plugin is not there anymore with Gephi 0.10 :(